# Add dynamic objects to Firestore

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, object, google-cloud-firestore

I would like an object that contains keys (session id) with a boolean value.

What I would like in Firestore:

```
sessions: [
  cs_test_foo,
  cs_test_bar
],
emailsSent: {
  cs_test_foo: false,
  cs_test_bar: false
}
```

What I'm currently doing:

```
let session = {
  id: 'cs_test_xxx'
}

docRef.update({
    sessions: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(session.id),
    emailsSent[session.id]: false
});
```

The *sessions* array works as intended but I'm having trouble creating this object

Comment: I don't see `emailsSent.cs_test_xxx` so that would be a null value.

Comment: No it was just an example, but it should be added to firestore, not return null

Comment: Even so, that would return `false: false`.  Boolean values are not valid keys.

Comment: I don't want boolean keys I want boolean values. If I use the example above I would like : `emailsSent: {cs_test_xxx: false}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your clarified requirements, you should use:
    `emailsSent: {[session.id]: false}`